# View pager with multiple fragments - Eventbus get registered multiple times

Tags: android, android-viewpager, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

I used `ViewPager` with 3 nested `Fragment`.I used `EventBus` for event handling.
But in my case subscribe method gets called by multiple times. Because `EventBus` gets register by multiple times.
    I have used these methods for `registering`a nd unregistering `EventBus`

```
     @Override
    public void onStop() {
        if (eventBus != null) {
            eventBus.unregister(this);
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (eventBus != null) {
            eventBus.unregister(this);
         }
        super.onPause();
     }

    @Override
     public void onResume() {
        if (eventBus != null) {
            eventBus.register(this);
        }
        super.onResume();
    }
```

My `viewpager` is available in `navigation drawer fragment`.
I was updated my `onresume()` like this but still same thing happens

```
 @Override
 public void onResume() {
     if (eventBus != null) {
          if (!eventBus.isRegistered(this)) {
             eventBus.register(this);
          }else{
             eventBus.unregister(this);
             eventBus.register(this);
         }
      }
      super.onResume();
```

}

These event received by multiple times thats why nested api gets called multiple times

```
@Subscribe
public void onEvent(Event event) {
    Responce Responce = event.responce;
    if (regResponce != null && regResponce.getStatus() == 0) {
         if (!isGenerateReportCalled) {
            isGenerateReportCalled = true;
            accountManager.generateReport(parameter); // server api call get called multiple times
        }
    } else {
        // error message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to register EventBus when fragment become visible to user. In ViewPager two fragments are prepared for display, one which is visible and next which will be replaced with first one that's why you get called onResume multiple times.

Check visibility and isResumed for fragment for registering EventBus.

Visibility state may be checked here:

```
public class SomeFrag extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
        if (visible) {
        // Register EventBus
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check is `EventBus` registered before or not

here you can check using method **isRegistered()**

```
if(!eventBus.isRegistered(this))
        eventBus.register(this);
```

Remove else part from `onResume()`.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
 if (eventBus != null) {
      if (!eventBus.isRegistered(this)) {
         eventBus.register(this);
      }
  }
  super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: plz check onevent method....i am new to stackoverflow....so formatting not done properly....thnks

Comment: my viewpager is from navigation drawer fragment....if i navigate to other fragment other than navigation drawer then these error happens

Comment: register event only in those fargment where you calling `event.post()`, not where  `onEvent()` method is. are you doing this?

Comment: actuly i used one AccountManager class where i used volleys onResponce() in which post event like                                                public void onResponse(Responce response) {
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(new Event(response));
                    }

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are registering event bus twice.

If event bus is not registered that time only you have to register event bus.

```
             @Override
             public void onResume() {
                if (eventBus != null) {
                        if (!eventBus.isRegistered(this)) {
                        eventBus.register(this);
                    }
                 }
                super.onResume();
            }
```

Comment: Your doing wrong else else part your again registering the eventbus